# CUDA efficient division?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

I would like to know if there is, by any chance an efficient way of dividing elements of an array. I am running with matrix values 10000x10000 and it a considerable amount of time in comparison with other kernels. Division are expensive operations, and I can't see how to improve it.

```
__global__ void division(int N, float* A, int* B){

  int row = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int col = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

  if((row < N) && (col <= row) ){
    if( B[row*N+col] >0 )
      A[row*N+col] /= (float)B[row*N+col];
  }

}
```

kernel launched with

```
  int N = 10000;
  int threads = 32
  int blocks = (N+threads-1)/threads
  dim3 t(threads,threads);
  dim3 b(blocks, blocks);
  division<<< b, t >>>(N, A, B);
  cudaThreadSynchronize();
```

Option B:

```
__global__ void division(int N, float* A, int* B){
  int k =  blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int kmax = N*(N+1)/2 
  int i,j;
  if(k< kmax){
    row = (int)(sqrt(0.25+2.0*k)-0.5); 
    col = k - (row*(row+1))>>1;
    if( B[row*N+col] >0 )
      A[row*N+col] /= (float)B[row*N+col];
  }
}
```

launched with

```
  int threads =192;
  int totalThreadsNeeded = (N*(N+1)/2;
  int blocks = ( threads + (totalThreadsNeeded)-1 )/threads;
  division<<<blocks, threads >>>(N, A, B);
```

Why is option B giving a wrong result even if the threadIds are the correct one? what is missing here?

Comment: So in this kernel, for the 1000x1000 case N=1000?

Comment: @talonmies: yes, sorry. Updated

Comment: You now have N=10000. Should that be N=1000?

Comment: No, it is actually 10000

Comment: So you are launching *100 million* threads and then deliberately having half of them do nothing more than a few IOPs and you are wondering why the kernel runs slowly? I think you are looking in the wrong place for a performance improvement. Slow division isn't your problem......

Comment: you are right, I think I am looking in the wrong place. however I have already tried launching `N*(N+1)/2` threads with a different kernel and I could not get the right result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you are launching an improbably huge grid (over 100 million threads for your 10000x10000 array example), and then because of the triangular nature of the access pattern in the kernel, fully half of those threads never do anything productive. So a enormous amount of GPU cycles are being wasted for no particularly good reason. Further, the access pattern you are using isn't allowing coalesced memory access, which is going to further reduce the performance of the threads which are actually doing useful work.

If I understand your problem correctly, the kernel is only performing element-wise division on a lower-triangle of a square array. If this is the case, it could be equally done using something like this:

```
__global__ 
void division(int N, float* A, int* B)
{
    for(int row=blockIdx.x; row<N; row+=gridDim.x) {
        for(int col=threadIdx.x; col<=row; col+=blockDim.x) {
            int val = max(1,B[row*N+col]);
            A[row*N+col] /= (float)val;
        }
    }
}
```

[disclaimer: written in browser, never compiled, never tested, use at own risk]

Here, a one dimension grid is used, with each block computing a row at a time. Threads in a block move along the row, so memory access is coalesced. In comments you mention your GPU is a Tesla C2050. That device only requires 112 blocks of 192 threads each to completely "fill" each of the 14 SM with a full complement of 8 blocks each and the maximum number of concurrent threads per SM. So the launch parameters could be something like:

```
int N = 10000;
int threads = 192;
int blocks = min(8*14, N);
division<<<blocks, threads>>>(N, A, B);
```

I would expect this to run considerably faster than your current approach. If numerical accuracy isn't that important, you can probably achieve further speed-up by replacing the division with an approximate reciprocal intrinsic and a floating point multiply.

Comment: @ talonmies: it looks a much better approach, however it does not speed up the code. Thanks for that, it really helped me to understand CUDA a bit more.

Comment: @Manolete: I have benchmarked it since I posted the answer and it most certainly does speed up the code. On a GTX670 I got about 7 times speed up over your original kernel. Are you sure you are timing this correctly?

Comment: @ talonmies: Let me double check, but the whole application takes same amount of time

Comment: @ talonmies: `N=8999` -> mykernel: `1.30893 sec`, yourKernel:`1.28179 sec`

Comment: What is the situation if you launch a kernel with an awful number of blocks (i.e >> 65535)? Could be the reason of a wrong result?

Comment: Yes, but you can easily test for that by checking the return codes of all CUDA calls for errors.

Comment: On a side note, for the loop approach to bring a significant improvement you probably need to at least partially unroll the inner loop (`pragma unroll N` with N a small integer) so that the compiler can move loads for multiple iterations forward and together.

Comment: @Manolete: I get: your kernel 50 milliseconds, mine 7 milliseconds for your original 10000x10000 case, timing done with nvprof using the CUDA 5 rc on a GTX670. Something is definitely wrong with your timing.

Comment: There are some parts that I don't understand in your code. For example, `blocks`. You chose the min between `8*14` and `(N+threads-1)/threads)`, why is that?

Comment: @Manolete As I said in the answer: your GPU can run at most 8 blocks per SM concurrently, and there are 14 SM. So the maximum number of concurrent blocks is 8*14, and if your data size is larger, each thread will process more than one entry. So the choice of block size should be limited to between 1 and 112.

Comment: @Manolete: The original grid size calculation was slightly broken. Have a look at the edited version. It might make more sense.

Comment: Do you think I could benefit here using shared memory?

Comment: @Manolete: no, not in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Because threads are executed in groups of 32, called warps, you are paying for the division for all 32 threads in a warp if both `if` conditions are `true` for just one of the threads. If the condition is `false` for many threads, see if you can filter out the values for which the division is not needed in a separate kernel.

The int to float conversion may itself be slow. If so, you might be able to generate floats directly in your earlier step, and pass B in as an array of floats.

You may be able to generate inverted numbers in the earlier step, where you generate the B array. If so, you can use multiplication instead of division in this kernel. `(a / b == a * 1 / b)`.

Depending on your algorithm, maybe you can get away with a lower precision division. There's an intrinsic, `__fdividef(x, y)`, that you can try. There is also a compiler flag, `-prec-div=false`.

Comment: Low threads per block? The block size is 1024 (32x32) which is the maximum on much recent hardware.....

Comment: @talonmies: Oops. Answer fixed.

Comment: Yes, that is the maximum number I can use in a Fermi 2050

Comment: Suspecting that the kernel is not using too much registers, , I would also tried with blocks of 192x1 threads to feed each SM with the maximum threads available.

Answer (score 2):

The very first thing to look at should be coalesced memory access. There is no reason for the non-coalesced pattern here, just exchange rows and columns for to avoid wasting a lot of memory bandwidth:

```
int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
...
A[row*N+col] ...
```

Even if this is run on compute capability 2.0 or higher, the caches are not large enough to remedy this suboptimal pattern.